# ABS and vehicle inspection

Tags: abs, inspection

Not sure how much this is a legal question but part of it is technical.

I have a car with a completely out of service ABS system as the technician claims (many erorrs in the control system). This is why the biannual inspection can't be passed - this car is no more allowed for use. (Germany)

My question is: afaik ABS itself is an option in terms there are old cars without it and still allowed for use (Clearly, ABS is great to reduce risks). Then, is it possible to "disable"/"remove" ABS? or is this component too deeply integrated?

Comment: Generally speaking, the rule in Europe is that if a safety feature was fitted to the vehicle when new, then it must exist and pass inspection.  I can't speak for the specifics of your case though.

Comment: There aren’t really many components in an ABS system, so it shouldn’t be too difficult to identify what is wrong.

Comment: they say it seems the control unit is damaged and will be quite expensive https://www.kfzteile24.de/magazin/werkstatt-service/abs-steuergeraet-wechseln - EUR 600 to 1400